# Strand sort in c# using arrays only

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, sorting

i have a homework using strand sort and i must take the growing sequence of numbers from the initial array and merge them together in the array that represents our result (C#)

Like this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHzKJ.jpg

So far i did something like that

```
public static int[] Str(int[] a)
    {
        int i, j, x ,temp,k=0,count=1;
        int size = a.Length;
        int len = a.Length;
        Strand = new int[size];
        Merged = new int[size];




        for (i = k; i < size; i++)
        {   
            x = a[i];
            Strand[0] = x;

            for (i = k; i < size; i++)      //checking if there's a bigger int than the first one
            {
                if (a[i] > x)
                {
                    x = a[i];

                }

            }

            for (i = k; i < len; i++)       
            {
                if (a[i] == x)     // checking if the max appears more than 1 time
                {

                    temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[len];
                    a[len] = temp;
                    len--;         //swaps the max numbers to the last position

                    Strand[count] = x;
                    count++;





                }

            }
            for (i = 0; i < count; i++) // cant find a way to put in the final merged and sorted array
            {

            }
            count = 1;
            k++;
        }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You always need to extract the first element into `strand`

```
 strand[0] = a[0]
 count = 1
```

Then you need to extract suitable elements into `strand`, shifting the rest of array

```
for i = 1 to size - 1
   if a[i] >= strand[count - 1]
        strand[count++] = a[i]
   else
        a[i - count] = a[i]
size = size - count
```

Then you need merge current `strand` and `merged`  - look for Merge procedure from MergeSort

Repeat these steps until `size` becomes 0